# Chrome extension copy and paste permission

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions

I'm writing a google chrome extension . it has two textareas and a button . once the button is clicked , it takes the code from the first textarea , does some logic on it and then pasts and shows the output in the second textarea . it works fine when I open the .html file in the browser but when I wanna use it as an extension it doesn't function and when I click the button nothing happens . I think it's got something to do with permissions , I've already put :        "contextMenus",
        "clipboardRead",
        "clipboardWrite" permissions on my manifest file but it still doesn't work . 
I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this .
thanks
edit : codes
**manifest.json** :

```
{
  "name": "MissLang Fix extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "fixing english to farsi typings.",
  "icons":{
    "128":"icon_128.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "missLangFix.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite"
  ]
```

}

**missLangFix.html** :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>MissLang Fix</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <div id="test"></div>
      <textarea class="txtarea" id="input" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
      <!--<div class="myBtn" onClick="myClick()">
        <b style="line-height:30px">fix</b>
      </div>-->
      <br/>
      <input type="button" value="fix" onclick="myClick()" />
      <br/>
      <textarea class="txtarea2" id="output" rows="4" cols="50" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js** :

```
window.onload = myOnload();
function myOnload(){
  var myString = document.getElementById("txtarea").innerHTML = "";
}

function myClick(){
  var myString = document.getElementById("input").value;

  for(var i=0;i<myString.length;i++){
    myString = myString.replace("q","ض");
    myString = myString.replace("w","ص");
    myString = myString.replace("e","ث");
  }

  //document.getElementById("txtarea").value = myString;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myString;
}
```

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: I edited the post and added codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the problem is the inline `onClick` handler on your button. Just move that to your script.js `onLoad` handler and it should start to work. First add an `id`to the button to make this easy.

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="fix" />
```

Next, get that button and add the onclick

```
function myOnload(){
  var myString = document.getElementById("txtarea").innerHTML = "";
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.onclick= function(){myClick()};
}
...
```

Here is a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/x2w2p/1/

Comment: @smtabatabaie  I made a small mistake in my onclick, I updated the answer.

Comment: @smtabatabaie It works just fine for me, you probably aren't defining the onload function correctly, are you doing it the same way I did for the onclick?

Comment: wow ,it's solved now . the reason was that the code inside onload function wasn't working , because of the first line : var myString = document.getElementById("txtarea").innerHTML . because there wasn't any "txtarea" id inside my html , "txtarea" was a class and I should have just used "input" id. and that first line was preventing the rest of the code to run . thanks so much BeardFist

Comment: If you want to know why onClick="myClick()" wouldn't have worked, read up on Content Security Policy (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html), specifically the section "Inline JavaScript will not be executed."